# add an object in my array each time I enter to the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

how can I add an object in my array each time I enter to my TableView
I put this code in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear methods but it seems to doesn't work 
 :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (!myArray) {
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [peopleListe insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    NSLog(@"%@",myArray);

}
```

when I put this code in a button it works

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called once, when the view loads.

`viewWillAppear` is called every time you go into that view.

If you want to do something each time a view appears, put the code in `viewWillAppear`.

EDIT: It's possible that your array is getting dealloc'd. Try setting a breakpoint in `dealloc` as a simple way to see if that's the case:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"BYE!); // <-- put your breakpoint here
}
```

If it is, you'll have to (a) store your data somewhere else, or (b) keep this view/controller from being dealloced.

Also, who is your `tableViewDelegate`? That will have to implement methods returning the number of items in the table view and so on. I recommend having a read through the docs to get all those relationships sorted out.

Comment: Thank you, I already put the same code in the viewWillAppear method. It doesn't work. It's like it forgets the datas in the array when I change my View

Comment: Thank you, you're right, my array is dealloc'd when I change my View. How can I do? should I stock the array in an other Method ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to have that array as a property/ivar of your view controller. The view controller may, and will, get deallocated when it's not used (e.g. if it's inside the navigation controller, and you tap the "back" button to go to the previous screen.) When the view controller gets deallocated, your array obviously ceases to exist.

I suggest creating keeping that array in a separate place, e.g. in a singleton data object, or even (as a quick short-term solution) your app delegate.

---

About the code you posted: keep in mind that `[UIViewController viewDidLoad]` is only called once during the view controller's lifecycle. It may get called more than once, but that would mean that the original instance has been dealloc'd (and your original array is gone).

Comment: I created a new class with a singleton data object but I got an error 2013-11-11 22:55:41.720 TestPOOSingleton[3126:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5aa4'

Comment: I changed my old array "myArray" by : [[Tableau instance]tableau]